# API de Conversiones Facebook // Error 505 en el servidor de producción

Tags: facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

¡Hola, comunidad de Stackoverflow!

Estoy usando el **SDK de Facebook** que clone a través del repositorio oficial de Desarrolladores de Facebook que adjunto en el siguiente enlace:

[Facebook PHP Business SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk)

Realizando algunas pruebas de código ofrecidas por la documentación oficial de los desarrolladores de Facebook y funcionan correctamente en mi **localhost**. Pero al migrar el código a mi servidor, obtengo el **Error 505**.

No sé si se requiere alguna configuración para probar el código en producción. El código que estoy probando localmente es el siguiente:

[AdsPixelEventsPost](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk/blob/main/examples/AdsPixelEventsPost.php)

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use FacebookAds\Object\AdsPixel;
use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Logger\CurlLogger;

$access_token = '<ACCESS_TOKEN>';
$app_secret = '<APP_SECRET>';
$app_id = '<APP_ID>';
$id = '<ADS_PIXEL_ID>';

$api = Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
$api->setLogger(new CurlLogger());

$fields = array();

$params = array(
    'data' => array(
        array(
            'event_name' => 'PageView',
            'event_time' => 1627583789,
            'user_data' => array('fbc' => 'fb.1.1554763741205.AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz1234567890',
            'fbp' => 'fb.1.1558571054389.1098115397',
            'em' => '309a0a5c3e211326ae75ca18196d301a9bdbd1a882a4d2569511033da23f0abd')
        )
    ),
);

echo json_encode((new AdsPixel($id))->createEvent($fields, $params)->exportAllData(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Como nota adicional, vale la pena mencionar que verifico mi solicitud **POST** a través del **Graph API Explorer** y me da una respuesta correcta.

Espero tu respuesta y ayuda.

Gracias.

¡Saludos!

Comment: Estás en [es.so]. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Además, te invito a leer [ask]. El código debes copiarlo y pegarlo en tu pregunta, un enlace al mismo no es de utilidad en el sitio, para mayor información puedes leer [mcve]. Haz clic en [edit] y realiza los cambios necesarios. Saludos